# NavigationLink inside LazyVGrid is not displayed correctly in swiftUI macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-scrollview

I am developing a cross platform app in SwifUI. On iPhone / iPad this code works really well on MacOS instead when I insert a NavigationLink the ForecastCardView is totally cut off. When I remove the NavigationLink everything is rendered correctly.

With NavigationLink

```
var FullSection: some View {
    LazyVGrid(columns: homeConfigurationUI.columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("test")) {
                  ForecastCardView(viewModel:  ForecastCardViewModel.initForTest())
            }.frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
        }
        .border(Color.yellow)
        .frame(minWidth: 300, idealWidth: 400, maxWidth: 600, minHeight: 0, idealHeight: 500, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
}
```

[Image With NavigationLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AI8B.png)

Without NavigationLink

```
var FullSection: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: homeConfigurationUI.columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
                ForecastCardView(viewModel:  ForecastCardViewModel.initForTest())
            }
            .border(Color.yellow)
            .frame(minWidth: 300, idealWidth: 400, maxWidth: 600, minHeight: 0, idealHeight: 500, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
    }
```

[Image Without NavigationLink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGiIi.png)

Everything is inside a ScrollView, I tried to insert a List a VStack, but no results. I tried to put a static frame on every single component, but nothing to do.

Comment: give ```.fixedSize()``` to ForecastCardView

Comment: @RajaKishan, Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately nothing changes :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set `buttonStyle` to `PlainButtonStyle()`:

```
var FullSection: some View {
    LazyVGrid(columns: homeConfigurationUI.columns, alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
            NavigationLink(destination: Text("test")) {
                  ForecastCardView(viewModel:  ForecastCardViewModel.initForTest())
            }
               .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()) // <— HERE
               .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
        }
        .border(Color.yellow)
        .frame(minWidth: 300, idealWidth: 400, maxWidth: 600, minHeight: 0, idealHeight: 500, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
}
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know why but it works great. Thank you so very very much :)

Comment: Every NavigationLink and Button in macOS has default background and height which is why the buttonstyle has to be set if you need different dimensions.

Comment: This is excellent. Thanks! I didn't even know NavigationLink was a button. It's not obvious.